# Suggestion for best solution - Python

Tags: python, list

I am learning python since last few days, I have read a problem on a site where they provided the solution with some built-in function. I have tried to do it without it, could you please check if i have done this correctly or should it be done with some other logic.

Problem:  Write a Python program to find the list in a list of lists whose sum of elements is the highest.

Solution:

## Code

```
num = [1,2,3], [4,5,6], [10,11,12], [7,8,9], [87,6,9], [87,7,9]

def func(l):
#function will return the element (list) whose sum is greater

    res = []
    flag = 0
    for index, items in enumerate(l):
        total = 0
        for item in items:
            total = total + item
            res.append(total)
            if total > res[index]:
                flag = index

    return l[flag]

#function call
print(func(num))
```

Comment: I think you want an extra set of brackets around the num value

Comment: yes that denotes it as a list

Comment: you have the list elements in it but your not stating those list elements are part of a list

Comment: `num = [[1,2,3], [4,5,6], [10,11,12], [7,8,9], [87,6,9], [87,7,9]]`

Comment: Might want to post this on https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @ironkey It does not matter it it's a list or a tuple in this case.

Comment: its easier to see and understand

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs on https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, your code is not correct. The problem is with the `res` list. Not sure that that's supposed to do, but you just keep appending items and then check the item at the index of the current outer loop. Instead, you should just keep track of the `best_sum` seen so far. Also, I'd suggest using better variable names.

```
def func(l):
    best_sum = 0
    best_index = 0
    for index, items in enumerate(l):
        total = 0
        for item in items:
            total = total + item
        if total > best_sum:
            best_index = index
            best_sum = total
    return l[best_index]

num = [1,2,3], [4,5,6], [10,11,12], [7,8,9], [87,6,9], [87,7,9], [1,1,1]
print(func(num))
```

Of course, using builtins `max` and `sum`, you can just do

```
print(max(num, key=sum))
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want the actual sum, you could take the max of the sum of each list.

```
m = max(sum(x) for x in num)
```

If you want the list:

```
for x in num:
    if sum(x) == m:
        print(x)
```

Comment: you can just do `max(sum(x) for x in num)` saves having to put all the values into a list

Comment: `Write a Python program to find the list` - To find the list and not the sum is what OP needs. @Chris

Comment: Your second solution sums each list twice.